# GCC cannot compile libcurl example: ‘CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T’ undeclared

Tags: c, linux, gcc, upload, libcurl

I’m trying to compile libcurl’s example code [`fileupload.c`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html) with GCC on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, getting the following error:

```
~ gcc fileupload.c 
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h:2738:0,
                 from fileupload.c:27:
fileupload.c: In function ‘main’:
fileupload.c:76:31: error: ‘CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME’?
       curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T, &total_time);
                               ^
fileupload.c:76:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

As `libcurl` I’ve installed Ubuntu’s `libcurl4-openssl-dev` package. Can anyone tell me why `CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T` is undeclared, although it should be [part of the library](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T.html)?

This is the example code:

```
 /***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998 - 2016, Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/
/* <DESC>
 * Upload to a file:// URL
 * </DESC>
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  struct stat file_info;
  curl_off_t speed_upload, total_time;
  FILE *fd;

  fd = fopen("debugit", "rb"); /* open file to upload */
  if(!fd)
    return 1; /* can't continue */

  /* to get the file size */
  if(fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info) != 0)
    return 1; /* can't continue */

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* upload to this place */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                     "file:///home/dast/src/curl/debug/new");

    /* tell it to "upload" to the URL */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* set where to read from (on Windows you need to use READFUNCTION too) */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);

    /* and give the size of the upload (optional) */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

    /* enable verbose for easier tracing */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    }
    else {
      /* now extract transfer info */
      curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD_T, &speed_upload);
      curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T, &total_time);

      fprintf(stderr, "Speed: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes/sec during %"
              CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T ".%06ld seconds\n",
              speed_upload,
              (total_time / 1000000), (long)(total_time % 1000000));

    }
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  fclose(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: documenttion for [`CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T.html) lists it has been added in 7.61.0 - check if your version of libcurl is not older.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker You are right, I have version 7.58.0 installed. It did not come to my mind that it could be an old version.

Comment: Older versions only have [CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an outdated version, see Sander De Dycker’s reply.